# Error: "ReferenceError: __gaTracker is not defined" for event of Google Analytic

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, socialengine, ab-testing, google-experiments

I am working with A/B testing of Google Analytic. I have to check conversion on two different landing pages of my site. To achieve this I have created new Goal in Google Analytic. In this goal set Event to detect click to *Signup Button*

Below code I have set onclick of Signup button to send event trigger.

```
<a onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Signup Click', 'Click', 'User Registration');" target="_blank" href="/signup">User Signup</a>
```

But when I click to this button, I am getting error of "ReferenceError: __gaTracker is not defined".

I tried to call it by using "ga" function but it also returning the same error.

Does anyone know how to make it working.

Comment: Paste the Google analytics library Js at footer or header of the page which you for from Google.

Comment: `__gaTracker` is a custom function defined by a [plugin : Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) in Wordpress. Instead using `ga` function, the plugin redefines the name of the function and each event fires the new function.

Comment: More info in this [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/note-change-of-global-function-ga-_gatracker/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste the Google analytics script at footer or header of your page.
This problem will be solved.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})(); //]]></script>

Comment: I have this Google analytic script in header and still I am getting error.

Comment: Sign in Google using Google analytics account and get the analytics code from there, then replace it with old one on your page

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It is working fine when I add analytics code directly into page. Just Need to replace function name "__gaTracker" to "ga".